# display data from php

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to populate a label or a text field with data from a php file. My code is below i have an error message on my xcode saying autorelease is unavailable. Is this the correct method of doing this? how do i fix this error?

Below is my code for my php

```
<?php
include( "./inc/header.inc.php");
include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");
?>
<?php

request=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TEAM WHERE TeamID = '9'");
if($request){
$count = mysql_num_rows($request);

if ($count==1){
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($request);
    $score = $rows['TeamName'];

    echo"$score";
}
}
?>
```

this is my xcode code in the viewdid load section

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.rugbycoachanalysis.com/applogintesting.php"];

    // to execute php code
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    // to receive the returned value
    NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    _labelTest.text =strResult;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove autorelease,its depricated.

Comment: Could you log `strResult`? Could you also log `dataURL`. A few guess: maybe `dataURL` is `null`,, or the encoding you used for `strResult` isn't the right one, so it return `null` for `strResult`.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using ARC which forbids manual release. so you can't release or autorelease.

```
NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
```

should be

```
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Besides that.

There are several other things that are wrong in your code. You are calling a synchronized request with `dataWithContentOfURL` which will block the thread. Also `stringWithString` is also a waste as you can simply declare your string as

```
NSString *strURL = @"www.rugbycoachanalysis.com/applogintesting.php"];
```

Update.. try new code to check for any errors also

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: strURL];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data,NSError *error){
    if (error == nil) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"result %@",string);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error in request %@",error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: labelTest is just appearing blank now in the php file i even changed it to `echo "$test";` which i has declared as `$test = test;` at the top of the php

Comment: then data isn't properly returned from the server or the request is failing. better to use `NSConnection sendAsynchronous`  request and check for any errors

Comment: thanks im a novice at this could you please explain in more detail

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html). So you don't have to bothor about memory deallocation.Remove `autorelease` and it will vanish the error.

```
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.rugbycoachanalysis.com/applogintesting.php"];

    // to execute php code
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    // to receive the returned value
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    _labelTest.text =strResult;
}
```

Comment: labelTest is just appearing blank now in the php file i even changed it to `echo "$test";` which i has declared as `$test = test;` at the top of the php

Comment: it cant be an error with the sql because ive eliminated that by making the variable test. So it be on xcodes end

Comment: it returns null, so how do i fix this?

Comment: @user3535330 See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to encode data, transmit it to iPhone app and decode it from there.

Your php code should be

```
<?php

request=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TEAM WHERE TeamID = '9'");
if($request){
$count = mysql_num_rows($request);

if ($count==1){
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($request);
    $score = $rows['TeamName'];

    echo json_encode($score);
}
}
?>
```

Objective C code should be

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.rugbycoachanalysis.com/applogintesting.php"];

    // to execute php code
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    // to receive the returned value
    NSError *error = nil;
    id object = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:dataURL
                      options:0
                      error:&error];
 NSLog(@"%@",object);
```

Comment: i got this error message `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'` and the app didnt open